# How update List of datagrid c# wpf caliburn.micro

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid, caliburn.micro

In this class :

```
 [Export(typeof(IScreen))]
    public class BolleViewModel : Screen
    {
              ....
    }
```

i have this List :

```
public List<Article> List { get; private set; }
```

This list is the Binding of Datagrid to List :

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArticle}"
            Margin="14,41,12,61" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="List">
```

I want that when I call the method UPDATE , updates the values ​​of the List and Datagrid.
This is my update method:

```
    public void Update(List<Article> list)
    {
        List = list;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("List");
    }
```

What i wrong ? ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caliburn.Micro doesn't support convention based binding for `DataGrid` out of the box, you can see this by checking the `ConventionManager` [static constructor](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ae616b84192450d079cf8b6fb91f0d8b8cda4e6a#src/Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight/ConventionManager.cs).

You can write your own convention using the `ConventionManager`, or you can just set the `ItemsSource` property binding instead in your view.

E.g.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArticle}"
        Margin="14,41,12,61" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"> ...
```

Other points:

1. `List` isn't a very good property name for your list of articles
2. Caliburn.Micro provides a lambda based override for `NotifyOfPropertyChange` which you should use to catch refactorings
3. A better pattern for implementing an INPC property is the following (this is because it's no longer the responsibility of the consumer who changes the property to invoke the `PropertyChanged` event)

**Use:**

```
private List<Article> articles;

public List<Article> Articles 
{ 
   get 
   {
       return this.articles;
   }

   private set
   {
       if (this.articles == value)
       {
           return;
       } 

       this.articles = value;
       this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Articles);
   }
}
```

As this is a collection type, you should also ensure that you always return a collection rather than null. This prevents the need for consumers to check to avoid null reference exceptions.

Comment: And if i don't use caliburn.micro for this datagrid , how i change my code ?

Comment: Ok. But don't work. 
I change the list of items in another method and then call the update method to make sure that the datagrid displays the new list, but does not work!

    public void Update(List<Article> list)
    {
        Articles = list;
    }

Comment: Your approach seems a bit convoluted. You have a reference to the selected article from the list view model which you pass into the detail view model. You can just update the properties of that reference in the detail view model. You should also not use public fields. Make them properties for those that you wish to bind, and make the fields that should be fields private.

Answer (score -1):

This is viewModel of Datagrid's view:

```
    [Export(typeof(IScreen))]
    public class BViewModel : Screen
    {
            private List<Article> articles;
            public List<Article> Articles
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.articles;
                }

                private set
                {
                    if (this.articles == value)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    this.articles = value;
                    this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Articles);
                }
            }

       public BolleViewModel()
       {
         Articles = recoverArticles(); //returns a list of articles
       }


       public void Update(List<Article> list)
       {
               Articles = list;
       }

        //is associated with a button
        public void Detail()
        {
            if(SelectedArticle!=null)
                WindowManager.ShowWindow(new DetailArticleViewModel(SelectedArticle, Articles), null, null);
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select an article","Error!",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }


   }
```

The DetailArticleViewModel change an item of Articles list and call Update method of BViewModel.

```
[Export(typeof(IScreen))]
    public class DetailArticleViewModel : Screen
    {
      public List<Article > GeneralList;
      public Article ArticleSelected;
      public BViewModel bw;


      public DetailArticleViewModel(Article art,List<Article> arts,BViewModel viewmodel)
      {
          ArticleSelected = art;
          GeneralList = arts;
          bw = viewmodel;
      }

      // is associated with a button
      public void Save()
      {
          var index = GeneralList.FindIndex(item => item.Code.CompareTo(ArticleSelected.Code)==0);
          GeneralList[index].Price = 900;
          bw.Update(List);

      }

    }
```

But the price of Selected articles is not 900 ! Why ?